# After splashscreen, a white blank screen comes and then webview is loaded

Tags: android, android-webview, splash-screen

In my app, there are two activities.First is Splashscreen and second is Webview activity.
After splash screen displays,i want to show my webview activity.But after splashscreen,for 2-3 seconds a blank white screen comes and then webview activity gets loaded.Any idea of how to ignore this white screen.
I looked into the solution for this issue in many posts but without success.
Any help will be appreciated.

Adding the code :
Splashscreen Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                    WebViewActivity.class));
        }
    }, DELAY);
}
```

Comment: There may be chance you made mistake in code.

Comment: maybe you have seperated, check in manifast file,

Comment: @TomerMor Can u plz elaborate the comment?

Comment: Webview takes some time to load it seems. So, how abt loading webview in AsynTask with a progressDialog in onPreexecute method?

Comment: Question is not clear... Do you want to avoid the white screen or show any other background color while loading the screen?

Comment: @SKT any of the solution will be fine..

Comment: Set a custom theme for your application. Then the background will be as per you have set or you can use progress bar and load webpage in asynchronous task as said by Braj.

Comment: @androiduser - sorry. You cant load webview from AsyncTask. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122089/webview-with-asynctask-on-android

Answer (score 1):

**Working code**

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {

protected boolean _active = true;

protected int _splashTime = 3000;

Thread splashTread;

private boolean stop = false;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

    splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if(_active) {
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }

            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {

                if(!stop){
                    startActivity(new Intent(WebActivity.this,Home.class));
                    finish();
                }
                else
                    finish();
            }
        }

    };
    splashTread.start();

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

        if(splashTread.isAlive())
            this.stop = true;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After completing the splash screen, the webpage load take some time. That's why you see a blank white screen appearing. Once web view starts load a progress bar.
try this  link . It will helpful to you.
http://www.technotalkative.com/android-load-webview-with-progressbar/

Comment: Please fix ` progress bar after completely load webview then invisible the progress bar`. Not able to understand.

Comment: @Peter this solution also shows a blank white screen for  2-3 seconds.

Comment: @peter : I guess this is default behaviour in android.It's still showing blank white screen.

Comment: @androiduser, by default webview background color is white. if you want to avoid white blank screen set transparent color for that webview.

Answer (score 0):

create two class files like WebActivity.java,home.java.

**WebActivity.java**

```
       Handler handler = new Handler();

    // run a thread after 2 seconds to start the home screen
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // make sure we close the splash screen so the user won't come
            // back when it presses back key

            finish();
            // start the home screen

            ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(WebActivity.this);

            //use this before calling intent
                          pd.setMessage("Processing...");

            pd.show();



            Intent intent = new Intent(WebActivity.this, Home.class);

            WebActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

        }

    }, 2000); // time in milliseconds (1 second = 1000 milliseconds) until the run() method will be called
```

**Home.java**

```
   webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");}

 public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient

 {

     @Override

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;

        }
 }
```

**Android manifest**

Just add the activity class and set internet permission to load webview

Comment: This is exactly what i have done..but after splashscreen completes and before webview loads a white blank screen appears for 2-3 seconds...