# Best practice using Webview in 2016? Loading WebView content with ASync?

Tags: android, webview, android-asynctask

I found several tutorials loading the webview with ASync like this: [Sample Tutorial Link](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/09/android-asynctask-example/)

But I also found this question for example where he suggests not to use WebView with ASync:
[StackOverflow reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122089/webview-with-asynctask-on-android)

But I don't understand why exactly and if this is just regarding a specific case. My problem is that I develop an app with Webview and my WebView is very slow. I have multiple activies and load the WebView on the onCreate method.

I just wanted to know what would be the best practice if the entire app content is based on Webview? Except the navigation menu (actionbar) is native.

Comment: app being slow is dependent on several factors such as device specs/app memory consumption and in your case even if the website is intensive it will also slow down the webview. You need to debug the working of your app more and analyse where is it slowing down.

Comment: So you mean this has nothing to do with using ASyncTask or not and I should concentrate improving the website itself? @Shubhank

Comment: url loading can be only part of the problem here. the async task might load the url in the background and make your app perform better but if in general the website is too heavy, the webview response will be sluggish. Asynctask only loads the url - user interaction is still on main thread.