# How to return Void function doInBackground in AsynTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, return

how to get the result of the function void in asyntask
I've tried like this but the application always stops

I want to implement a progressbar in webview with asyntask when the waiting process

note: I've read this [Webview with asynctask on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122089/webview-with-asynctask-on-android)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edInput;
    Button btnCari;
    WebView webView;
    public String dataUrl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initUI();
        initEvent();
        new asynCaller().execute();
    }


    private void initUI(){
        edInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        dataUrl = edInput.getText().toString();
        btnCari = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    }

    private void initEvent() {
        btnCari.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String dataUrl = edInput.getText().toString();
                dataUrl = dataUrl.isEmpty() ? "google" : dataUrl;
                loadWebview("https://" + dataUrl + ".com");
                message("Data link is "+dataUrl);
            }
        });
    }

    private void message(String pesan){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,pesan, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private boolean checkConnection(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

    private void statusConnection(){
        if (checkConnection()){
            message("Device Online");
        }else{
            message("Device Offline");
        }
    }

    private void loadWebview(String url){
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

    }

    public class asynCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
//            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
//            progressDialog.show();
            message("persiapan");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            statusConnection();
            if (checkConnection()) {
                dataUrl = dataUrl.isEmpty() ? "google" : dataUrl;
                loadWebview("https://" + dataUrl + ".com");
                message("Data link is " + dataUrl);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
//            progressDialog.dismiss();
            message("selesai");
        }
    }
```

**EDITED**
thank's for your help 
i change a method doInBackground to onProgressUpdate for showing Webview and work and i get new problem with progress dialog, the progress dialog can't dismiss()

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            publishProgress();
            return url;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            url = edInput.getText().toString();
            progressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Pesan","Memuat . . .",true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            loadWeb(url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: set Third parameter of asy task as string.

Comment: You cannot update your UI from background thread.

Answer (score 1):

Change Your `doInBackground()` return type to `String/int`

```
   public class asynCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
    //            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    //            progressDialog.show();
                message("persiapan");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                statusConnection();
                if (checkConnection()) {
                    dataUrl = dataUrl.isEmpty() ? "google" : dataUrl;
                    loadWebview("https://" + dataUrl + ".com");
                    message("Data link is " + dataUrl);
                }
                return "Your Message";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
    //            progressDialog.dismiss();
    Log.d("Reached_postExe",result);
                message("result");
            }
        }
```

Comment: doInBackground can't return String

Answer (score 0):

The following is the code I would use, refactored from your own code. I have taken the liberty of making changes to your messaging to make it more meaningful in the console.

```
   public class AsynCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        System.out.println("AsynCaller.onPreExecute called");
        // progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        // progressDialog.show();
        message("AsynCaller.onPreExecute called");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        System.out.println("AsynCaller.doInBackground called");
        statusConnection();
        final String result; // making it final forces it's definition whichever logic flow the code takes, which is good practice for a returned value 
        if (checkConnection()) {
            dataUrl = dataUrl.isEmpty() ? "google" : dataUrl;
            final String fullUrl = "https://" + dataUrl + ".com";
            loadWebview(fullUrl);
            result = "AsynCaller.doInBackground loadWebView called with " + fullUrl;
        } else {
            result = "AsynCaller.doInBackground checkConnection() is false");
        }
        // message(result); this is unnecessary as the Toast will appear due to the message() call in onPostExecute
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("AsynCaller.onPostExecute called");
        // progressDialog.dismiss();
        message(result);
    }
}
```

I would, if I were you, replace the System.out calls with Log.d() so that the console output is only done in debuggable mode and not in any release version of your app. The reference for this is here [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

As a last suggestion I would not have the ProgressDialog being a property of the AsyncTask but instead call methods in MainActivity, as you have done with message() for instance. There are issues, for instance in this case, around possible memory leaks etc. if an object effectively holds a reference to an Activity context and the Activity is destroyed while the object continues to exist, as would be the case for a running AsyncTask.