# How to add progress bar in YouTube Web view in Android Studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, webview, progress-bar

I wanted to add youtube link to my web view in android Studio.So I added with few customization.(That is full screen enable).
So Further I want to add progress bar  with percentage count to my web view.I tried but no result...How to enable progress bar(with percentage count) in my web view.Progress bar should hide after loading url.
Thank you

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    private FrameLayout customViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback;
    private View mCustomView;
    private myWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;
    private myWebViewClient mWebViewClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        customViewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
        webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);

        mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
        webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/user/ThatWasEpic11/videos");
    }

    public boolean inCustomView() {
        return (mCustomView != null);
    }

    public void hideCustomView() {
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        if (inCustomView()) {
            hideCustomView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            if (inCustomView()) {
                hideCustomView();
                return true;
            }

            if ((mCustomView == null) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private Bitmap mDefaultVideoPoster;
        private View mVideoProgressView;

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, CustomViewCallback callback) {
           onShowCustomView(view, callback);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view,CustomViewCallback callback) {

            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }
            mCustomView = view;
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.addView(view);
            customViewCallback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {

            if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this);
                mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_progress, null);
            }
            return mVideoProgressView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            super.onHideCustomView();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            if (mCustomView == null)
                return;

            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            customViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

            mCustomView = null;
        }
    }

    class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mCustomViewContainer != null)
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    else if (myWebView.canGoBack())
        myWebView.goBack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}

}
```

Here is activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/liProgressContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLoadingPercentage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/customViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Probably dup, check this answer
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122089/webview-with-asynctask-on-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122089/webview-with-asynctask-on-android)

Comment: thank you for code.but it's not about percentage count